# Dynamically setting the status bar color in Android is not working

Tags: android, android-actionbar, statusbar, android-statusbar

I am developing an Android application. In my app, I am setting the action bar color according to color code that come from server. Setting the background color is fine and working. But I also want to change the color of status bar according to color code of action bar. I want to darken the color and set it on status bar like below screenshot.

[image]

I set the status bar color like this in activity

```
private void setStatusBarColor()
    {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            Window window = getWindow();

            // clear FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS flag:
            window.clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS);

            // add FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS flag to the window
            window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS);

            // finally change the color
             window.setStatusBarColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.statusBarColor));
        }
    }
```

But for this time I need to change the color dynamically. I tested the with mock color value but not working.

In activity onCreate method

```
       teamColorCode = "#EB6343";
        if(teamColorCode!=null && !teamColorCode.isEmpty())
        {
            int color = Color.parseColor(teamColorCode);
            getSupportActionBar().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(color));
            //set for action bar
            float[] hsv = new float[3];
            Color.colorToHSV(color,hsv);
            hsv[2] *= 0.8f; // value component
            color = Color.HSVToColor(hsv);
            setStatusBarColor(color);
        }
```

As you can see I assigned a color code value to teamColorCode  variable. Then I tried to darken that color and set the color of status bar. this is how I set status bar color.

```
 private void setStatusBarColor(int color)
    {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            Window window = getWindow();

            // clear FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS flag:
            window.clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS);

            // add FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS flag to the window
            window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS);

            // finally change the color
            if(color>0)
            {
                window.setStatusBarColor(color);
            }
            else{
                window.setStatusBarColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.statusBarColor));
            }
        }
    }
```

This is what I get:

[image]

As you can see status bar color is not changing. How can I change status bar color darkening the action bar color?

Comment: Are you try set same color to StatusBar as have ActionBar? If yes you can do that. Check https://material.google.com/style/color.html#color-color-palette , ActionBar set 500 and StatusBar set 700 color.

Comment: No. Darken the color of action bar. Then set to status bar.

Comment: My color code is dynamic. Coming from server.

Answer (score 2):

I also tried to achieve the same effect, dynamically generate a dark color for the status bar, so please take a look on how i did it.

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
    Window window = this.getWindow();
    window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DRAWS_SYSTEM_BAR_BACKGROUNDS);
    window.clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TRANSLUCENT_STATUS);
    window.setStatusBarColor(getDarkColor(Color.GREEN, 0.7));
}
```

Dark color generation method (when value is lower, the color you get is darker).

```
public int getDarkColor(int color, double value) {
    int r = Color.red(color);
    int g = Color.green(color);
    int b = Color.blue(color);
    return Color.rgb((int) (r * value), (int) (g * value), (int) (b * value));
}
```

Comment: I just got the same result.

Comment: Are your Android version is Lollipop or higher?

Comment: Yes. I am testing with real device with version 6+

Answer (score 0):

use this code for changing status bar color (darker then toolbar color)

```
   factor=0.8f; 
    int a = Color.alpha(toolbarcolor);
    int r = Math.round(Color.red(toolbarcolor) * factor);
    int g = Math.round(Color.green(toolbarcolor) * factor);
    int b = Math.round(Color.blue(toolbarcolor) * factor);
    int statusColor=Color.argb(a,
            Math.min(r, 255),
            Math.min(g, 255),
            Math.min(b, 255));

if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        Window window = MainActivity.this.getWindow();
        window.setStatusBarColor(statusColor);
    }
```

`